# does crystal reports perform join on referential key constraints alone?

Tags: sql, database, join, crystal-reports

Based on the conditions specified in the "Record Selection Formulas", the Crystal Reports 2008 is performing INNER JOIN only on the referential key constraints.

So, for tables that are not related, all it does is pattern-matching. It looks for any attribute names that match and performs JOINS on them.

Is there a work around for this? Can I specifically tell Crystal Reports on what condition to JOIN?

Please let me know..

Comment: In earlier versions of Crystal you could view the auto-generated SQL and modify it. Not sure about 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify how tables join together, IE: which fields link and a the type of join in the *"Database Expert's links"* tab.  Crystal call joins *"links"*.

You are correct in saying that crystal will pattern match similarly named fields/data types and automatically join them.

In the database expert there is a button to delete all links between tables or you can manually delete links by clicking them and pressing delete.

You can modify links by right clicking and selecting modify.  From there you can choose one of four standard join types, `INNER, LEFT OUTER, RIGHT OUTER, FULL OUTER`.

Hope this helps.